# Parsing XML via ORACLE Query using XMLTYPE/XMLTABLE

Tags: sql, xmltype, xmltable

I Wish to return a section of XML from a Datatable using SQL.

```
<Layer>
                <LayerName>ALPHA</LayerName>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-5</x>
                    <y>2</y>
                </coordinates>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-5</x>
                    <y>1</y>
                </coordinates>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-5</x>
                    <y>0</y>
                </coordinates>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-5</x>
                    <y>-1</y>
                </coordinates>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-5</x>
                    <y>-2</y>
                </coordinates>
                <LayerName>BETA</LayerName>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-4</x>
                    <y>3</y>
                </coordinates>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-4</x>
                    <y>2</y>
                </coordinates>
                <LayerName>GAMMA</LayerName>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-4</x>
                    <y>1</y>
                </coordinates>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-4</x>
                    <y>0</y>
                </coordinates>
                <coordinates>
                    <x>-4</x>
                    <y>-1</y>
                </coordinates>
            </Layer>
```

I'm taking the approach of trying to bring the data back as an XML Table but cannot seem to get it to work as expected.

```
SELECT X.PRODUCT, X2.LayerName, X2.X, X2.Y
FROM( 
        SELECT PRODUCT, XMLTYPE(xml_data) AS xmlData FROM XMLTABLE) X,
      XMLTABLE('/Layer' PASSING x.xmlData columns 
         LayerName varchar2(100) PATH 'LayerName',
         X number PATH 'coordinates/x',
         Y number PATH 'coordinates/y'
      ) X2
```

[Results Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuGMN.png)

I tried with various versions of columns and can get EITHER the LayerName or the X,Y but not both

Comment: Hi - please don’t link to images, add all information to your question as editable text. Also, format your code as code do that it is readable